# Implementing a composition relationship in an abstract class definition

Tags: java, oop

I'm going through past exam papers for an OOP exam and I've come across a question:
Could the below class definition be used to implement a composition relationship between the classes Person and Brain?

```
abstract class Person{
   private Brain brain;
   Person(Brain humanBrain) {
      brain = humanBrain;
   }
}
```

I was under the impression that from the code given there is already a composition relationship between the two however as the question also asks for code samples I presume I'm wrong. An explanation of how to implement the composition or moreover why this already isn't considered a composition relationship between the two would be appreciated.

Comment: Person **has a (have)** Brain; clear composition.

Comment: That class definition already implements a composition relationship between Person and Brain. Perhaps the answer is just "Yes" and you can move on? There's nothing else here to explain, since your impression is correct.

Comment: Private? Maybe `protected Brain brain;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the UML Composition definition and we can find a lot of examples in SO and internet. **But**, I think we should look in-depth.

**First of all**: Clarification about **Composition**. 
In Composition ([see reference](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html)):

> if a composite (whole) is deleted, all of its composite parts are
>   "normally" deleted with it.

Consider this example:

```
class Person {
   private final Brain brain;
   Person(Brain humanBrain) {
      brain = humanBrain;
   }
}
```

And in other parts of code we can define like this:

```
Brain b = new Brain(); 
       // or we have an instance of Brain in other scopes
       // not exactly in this scope

Person p1 = new Person(b);
Person p2 = new Person(b);
```

So, in this code, we can set one instance of `Brain` to two different `Persons`.

**Note**: In composition, **we should manage the life cycle of instances**. Only defining a `private final` of any class, do not show the Composition between them.

For example the below example can be a Composition. Because instances of "Part" deleted when the "whole" is deleted:

```
public class House {    
   private final Room room;

   public House() {    
       room = new Room();
   }
}
```

**In Composition:** 
The "whole" may directly be responsible for creation or destruction of the "part". Or it may use a "part" that has been already created and managed from external of class (by other parts of code). In this case, deletion of "part" should be managed by external code and the "part" should be deleted immediately after the "whole" deletion.

We should establish a mechanism to delete "part" when the "whole" is deleted. **If we do not delete the "part" and use it in other "wholes" it is aggregation**.

**To sum up** 
Detecting the Composition in source code needs to have whole implementation of code. And we should **ensure** that the "part" is deleted immediately when the "whole" is delete.

The other point in the question is **abstract**. So we don't have Object Composition or Object Aggregation in that code.

**Finally**: the relationship in the question is Composition (only based on the **concept** of Person and Brain). But, from the given source code it is not Composition yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to define Brain as final, distinguishing it from Aggregation, as detailed here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/ifference-between-association-vs-composition-vs-aggregation.html